# How to use MTLLoader in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I'm a student in computer science and I have a project where I need to create a 3d scene with a train. I loaded the model correctly but the texture is a .mtl file.
So I looked the official documentation and I saw the MTLLoader. The problem is it's not in three.js and I need to use the code from
 https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js 
and I have no idea how to do it. 
I tried to do an import like my teacher did in the sample of code he gave us :
 import { OBJLoader } from './threejs/OBJLoader.js';
But it didn't work, the console told me I couldn't use THREE. in my mtl file. So I ask for help here ! Thank you

PS : Sorry if I made mistakes or if I didn't use the website correctly it's the first time I post here